# How to change the sprite image and variables

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have this game where players can buy in game upgrades to their vehicles.  But I don't know how to change the image of the sprite and the variables. Please help

```
var tank1 = SKSpritenode(imageName: "firsttank")
var tank2 = SKSpritenode(imageName: "secoundtank")

tank1.size = cgsize(width: 100, height: 100)
tank1.position = cgpoint(x: self.frame.size,width/2, y:     
self.frame.size.height/2)
self.addchild(tank1)

tank2.size = cgsize(width: 250, height: 250)
tank2.position = cgpoint(x: self.frame.size,width/2, y: self.frame.size.height/2)
self.addchild(tank2)
```

How can I make the first sprite (tank1) to turn into tank 2 when a button has been clicked???

Comment: I think you need a state that says what tank1 is, and then depending on that state you can set the image and variables.

Comment: Can you be more specific, what do you mean about state???. Do you mean like enum or class???

Comment: Add variables/enums to keep track of the sprites state.

Answer (score 0):

You can write:

```
tank1.texture = tank2.texture
```

or:

```
tank1.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "secondtank")
```

Comment: tank1.size = tank2.size and so on